# Can CFTHREAD be used for LDAP housekeeping?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

Can I keep two records in LDAP in sync using CFTHREAD?

I need to check if a record is still valid by looking up a cn elsewhere. So if it is invalid I want to delete it. This means getting all current records of the type I want, deleting them all and adding them all again (minus the one I dont want)

Comment: Are you thinking of a gateway that runs continuously? cfthreads can run any code afaik

Comment: Need a little more information here, I think. Why CFTHREAD and not, for instance, a ColdFusion scheduled task?

Comment: Your problem description does not indicate why you think that cfthread is useful to you. Threads are for concurrency, but which part of your problem requires such a thing? Sounds all quite straightforward to me...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using sql server anywhere?  You can create linked servers to ldap servers using the adsi provider.

Then you can use SQL to do this maintenance.  I find doing ldap queries this way a little easier and more flexible than the cfldap tag.

Only caveat since you are updating is providing the proper permissions to the ldap server to do the updates.